# Generic WPF Binding in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I would like to write a generic function that creates bindings given a pair of FrameworkElements (source/target), a DependencyProperty, and a BindingMode (purely for demonstration/experimentation purposes, trying to create 5 buttons that demonstrate each BindingMode between a slider and a Label.FontSize).

Here is the function I've got to start with:

```
private void create_Binding(FrameworkElement source, FrameworkElement target, 
                            DependencyProperty property, BindingMode mode) {
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = source;
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
            binding.Mode = mode;
            target.SetBinding((target.GetType()).property, binding);
}
```

Issue: I get CS1061 "'Type' does not contain a definition for 'property'..." on the `SetBinding()` call. I've tried casting target to a few different types on the last line, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
private void CreateBinding(
    object sourceObject, string sourcePropertyName,
    DependencyObject targetObject, DependencyProperty targetProperty,
    BindingMode bindingMode)
{
    var binding = new Binding
    {
        Source = sourceObject,
        Path = new PropertyPath(sourcePropertyName),
        Mode = bindingMode
    };

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(targetObject, targetProperty, binding);
}
```